Base Case of Theorem III.5.2 in Silverman's AEC
I am studying Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, and I am a little confused on the base case of the following theorem:

Theorem 5.2. Let $E$ and $E'$ be elliptic curves, let $\omega$ be an invariant differential on $E$, and let $$\phi,\psi: E' \to E$$ be
isogenies. Then $$(\phi+\psi)^*\omega = \phi^*\omega + \psi^*\omega.$$

Silverman posits that if $\phi = [0]$ or $\psi = [0]$, then the result is clear.
Suppose $\phi = [0]$. Then what we need to prove becomes:
$$([0] + \psi)^*\omega = [0]^*\omega + \psi^*\omega,$$
and since $[0] + \psi = \psi$, we need to show that
$$0 = [0]^*\omega.$$
Picking any point $P \in E$, we would have that
$$ [0]^*\omega(P) = (\omega \circ [0])(P) = \omega(O) = 0.$$
However, it is explicitly shown earlier in the book that the invariant differential has no zeroes or poles! Hence $\omega$ cannot have a zero at $O$, the point at infinity.
What is wrong here?

The equation $\phi^* \omega = \omega \circ \phi$ only applies to a non-constant map $\phi$ (Silverman, Chapter 2, section 4). If $\phi$ is constant, then $\phi^* \omega = 0$ must be the right definition, although I can't find that in Silverman.
